# Electric flux, is q/absolute permitivity, but is also cross product of electric field and area vector, then why doesnt it increase with radius?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

A charge q is enclosed by a gaussian spherical surface of radius R if the radius is doubled the outward flux will remain the same. How is that possible if flux is also defined as the cross product of electric field and area vector?

Answer (score 1):

From the integral form of Gauss's law, electric flux $\phi$ through a differential area $d\vec A$ due to an electric field $\vec E$ summed over the a closed surface is

$$\phi=\oint \vec E \cdot d\vec A\tag{1}$$

To simplify the solution to (1) for a sphere, let the charge $q$ be located at the center of the sphere. Then electric field strength is constant (comes out of the integral) over the surface of the sphere and is, as a function of the radius,

$$E=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_{o}r^2}\tag{2}$$

The area of the sphere is

$$A=4\pi r^2\tag{3}$$

Substituting (2) and (3) into (1)

$$\phi=\frac{q}{\epsilon_o}$$

for an electric flux that is independent of the sphere radius.

Physically, as you increase the radius of the sphere the strength of the electric field (density of the electric field lines) at the surface decreases, but at the same time the area crossed by the lines increases so that the electric flux over the entire surface remains constant.

Hope this helps.